# Angaben einer Informationsquelle

Tags: preposition

**Laut** fordert den Genetiv. Manchmal ohne Artikel und Genitivendung verwendet (z.B. Laut Paragraf 4).

I have already understand the rule, and i came across an exercise with *»wissenschaftliche Untersuchungen«.*
Should I write

> laut **wissenschaftlichen Untersuchungen** können Mäuse singen

or

> laut **wissenschaftlicher Untersuchungen** können Mäuse singen

?

And is there any other tipp that you recommend me about this subject?

Answer (score 3):

*Laut* is a preposition that can either take dative or genitive, with no difference in meaning, so, your choice.

There is a rule that says "use *laut* with dative when the genitive plural looks identical to the nominative plural", though:

> <s>Laut der Mütter an der Schule schmeckt den Kindern das Essen nicht</s>
>
> Laut den Müttern an der Schule schmeckt den Kindern das Essen nicht

This rule would probably not apply to the example in your question, because both the dative **and** genitive of *Untersuchungen* are identical to the nominative form. Using dative here wouldn't improve anything. So again, your choice.

Comment: How could *der Mütter* be anything but genitive?

Comment: @CarstenS *Mütter* (the genitive) and *Mütter* (the nominative) are definitely equal. I was not talking about articles.

Comment: So the rule is: "Use *laut* with dative if the genitive plural looks identical to the nominative plural, unless it also looks the same as the dative plural, all the while ignoring articles"?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Nah. The **rule** is what I wrote above. But your *interpretation*  is the same as mine.